# USB Mighty Mouse odd behaviour

Tags: macos, mouse

I am having an issue with my mouse, it seems to slow down by about 50% when the cursor gets to a button or something clickable.

Dose any one know what this issue might be?

I have plugged in a wireless Microsoft mouse and its not displaying the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is how I sorted the issue out.

So apparently this is a system feature.

I installed a application called Steermouse [found here](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/).

The application has a option to disable this feature.

[image]